# found 1 high severity vulnerability(angular material installation)

Tags: angular, installation, angular-material

I tried to install angular material using `npm install @angular/material --save` but the result was:

```
npm WARN @angular/material@7.3.7 requires a peer of @angular/cdk@7.3.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @angular/material@7.3.7
updated 1 package and audited 42613 packages in 16.398s
found 1 high severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

I also tried `npm audit fix` and got this result:

```
npm WARN @angular/material@7.3.7 requires a peer of @angular/cdk@7.3.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

up to date in 7.989s
fixed 0 of 1 vulnerability in 42613 scanned packages
  1 vulnerability required manual review and could not be updated
```

Then I tried `nmp audit` and this is the result:

```
                       === npm audit security report ===


                                 Manual Review
             Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve

          Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance


  High            Arbitrary File Overwrite

  Package         tar

  Patched in      >=4.4.2

  Dependency of   @angular-devkit/build-angular [dev]

  Path            @angular-devkit/build-angular > node-sass > node-gyp > tar

  More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/803

found 1 high severity vulnerability in 42613 scanned packages
  1 vulnerability requires manual review. See the full report for details.
```

Why do I get this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Just install the cdk it's needed for materials `npm install @angular/cdk --save`

Comment: @Swoox:   + @angular/cdk@7.3.7
added 2 packages from 1 contributor and audited 42616 packages in 15.819s
found 1 high severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Comment: @Swoox: It seems it gives me the same error with installing cdk too.

Answer (score 1):

The new version of tar has been released.
[npm/node-tar#212 (comment)](https://github.com/npm/node-tar/issues/212#issuecomment-492463507)

Delete the folder `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, then execute the commands:

1. `npm install`
2. `npm audit`
3. `npm audit fix`
4. `npm audit`